# Are there any iPython-like shells for Ruby or Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ipython

I love iPython and am learning RoR along with some libraries like Mechanize and I'd like to be able to easily see what I'm working with in terms of introspection. I would like to be able to type "." + TAB and see.

Comment: In ipython, you can suffix an object, method, attribute with "?" to get the embedded documentation. Is there an equivalent in irb or any of the other shells? That functionality makes for great command exploration.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is an irb tool to help autocomplete

```
require 'irb/completion'
```

Comment: wirble listed below adds color coding to completion - that gets my vote for being more similar to ipython

Answer (score 19):

You should take a look at [Pry](https://pry.github.io/) (an IRB alternative and runtime developer console). It isn't as advanced as the current version of IPython, but it's the most advanced developer console we have in Ruby.

Answer (score 4):

try IRB  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Ruby_Shell, or the rails console http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html.  I don't know if either of them have autocomplete, but they are quality tools.

Comment: Currently both `irb` and `rails console` provide auto-completion.

Answer (score 4):

There is an IPython notebook backed by Ruby kernel. [Details about the project](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/minrk/4689728)

Answer (score 3):

[Wirble](http://pablotron.org/software/wirble/) is a convenient, if infrequently-updated way of bringing together some of these tools. It's not quite as complete as iPython, but gets pretty close. Among other things, it pulls in `irb/completion`.

For rails, you can do the same, but use `script/console` from your rails' root directory to start irb.

Comment: pretty much dead unless I'm missing smothing